# How do I get the output to print none if there is no binary, ternary, ect from the input?

Tags: c

This is the code I have for a project that if you type in the even and odd base of the number as well as a set of up 20 numbers with the last one being -1 it would convert the numbers with the base input but I need it to print none if there isnt any for it

[like the example here where i need it to print none on the binary since there isnt any binary number for it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsHmx.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int oddInput();
int evenInput();
void dataInput();
void convert(int n, int b);
void checkType(int base);
void printOdd(int arr[], int base);
void printEven(int arr[], int base);

int dataset[20];

int main()
{

    int oddbase = oddInput();
    int evenbase = evenInput();

    dataInput();
    printf("\n");
    printOdd(dataset, oddbase);
    printf("\n");
    printEven(dataset, evenbase);

    return 0;
}

void dataInput()
{
    int i, temp;
    printf("Enter upto 20 integers: ");
    for (i = 0; temp != -1; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        dataset[i] = temp;
    }
}

int oddInput()
{
    int oddbase;
    printf("Enter the base for odd numbers: ");
    scanf("%d", &oddbase);
    while (oddbase < 2 || oddbase > 9)
    {
        printf("\nError! base must be in the range of 2 to 9");
        printf("\nEnter the base for odd numbers: ");
        scanf("%d", &oddbase);
    }
    return oddbase;
}

int evenInput()
{
    int evenbase;
    printf("Enter the base for odd numbers: ");
    scanf("%d", &evenbase);
    while (evenbase < 2 || evenbase > 9)
    {
        printf("\nError! base must be in the range of 2 to 9");
        printf("\nEnter the base for odd numbers: ");
        scanf("%d", &evenbase);
    }
    return evenbase;
}

void convert(int n, int b)
{
    int rem; //value for remainder from modulus operation
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        rem = n % b;
        convert(n / b, b);
        printf("%d", rem);
    }
}

void checkType(int base)
{
    switch (base)
    {
    case 2:
        printf("Binary Values: ");
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("Ternary Values: ");
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("Quaternary Values: ");
        break;
    case 5:
        printf("Quinary Values: ");
        break;
    case 6:
        printf("Senary Values: ");
        break;
    case 7:
        printf("Septenary Values: ");
        break;
    case 8:
        printf("Octal Values: ");
        break;
    case 9:
        printf("Nonary Values: ");
        break;
    }
}

void printEven(int arr[], int base)
{
    int i = 0;
    checkType(base);
    do
    {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
          convert(arr[i], base);
          printf(" ");
        }
        i++;
    } while (arr[i] != -1);
}

void printOdd(int arr[], int base)
{
    int i = 0;
    checkType(base);
    do
    {
        if (arr[i] % 2 != 0)
        {
            convert(arr[i], base);
            printf(" ");
        }
        i++;
    } while (arr[i] != -1);
}
```

Comment: Just keep an int in printEven and printOdd that you initialize to zero and increment each time convert is called - then after the loop check if it is zero and print "none"

Answer (score 0):

Use a state variable to remember if something has been printed. Like:

```
void printOdd(int arr[], int base)
{
    int i = 0;
    int did_print = 0;
    checkType(base);
    do
    {
        if (arr[i] % 2 != 0)
        {
            did_print = 1;  
            convert(arr[i], base);
            printf(" ");
        }
        i++;
    } while (arr[i] != -1);
    
    if (did_print == 0)
    {
        printf("none");
    }
}
```

**Other comments:**

Your `evenInput` function prints "odd" instead of "even".

And... Here:

```
int i, temp;
printf("Enter upto 20 integers: ");
for (i = 0; temp != -1; i++)
```

`temp` is uninitialized when the loop starts. Make sure to initialize it to some value, e.g. zero. Further, you should make sure not to overflow the array. Like:

```
int i, temp = 0;
printf("Enter upto 20 integers: ");
for (i = 0; temp != -1 && i < 20; i++) // stop when input is -1 OR the array is full
{
    ...
}
arr[19] = -1;  // Make sure the always have a -1 at the last position
```

Also notice that the use of -1 as a "no more integers" sentinel means that the user can only give 19 integers. The last element in the array must be -1.

And ... don't make `dataset` a global variable. Put it into `main` and pass it to the `dataInput` function - just like you do with e.g. `printOdd`

And.. always check the value returned by `scanf`. Like:

```
if (scanf("%d", ...) != 1)
{
    // Input error
    ... add error handling ...
}
```